Issue in Table of contents page
I am writing my reseach thesis and just caught in very strange situation.on table of content page  i get red boxes arounf each line.i am attaching the photo of error.anyone could guide me to remove the bug

Welcome to TeX.SX! These are just hyperlinks (see there). Use \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}. Next time, please provide a minimal working example (MWE), and post real code in your question (that we can copy/paste), not a screenshot.
